# Android take screenshot from code, with root access

Tags: java, android, screenshot, framebuffer

I need to take a screenshot from a service running in the background. The screenshot can be of the app in the foreground, even if its not my app, which is why I can't use DrawingCache. I've searched around and found this

`process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c cat /dev/graphics/fb0");
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();`

But I don't know what to do with the stream. How do I get it into a bitmap? I don't need to save it to file I just need to keep it in a variable. This is for rooted phones.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: When you have the inputstream why don't you just Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); ?

Comment: Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is) doesn't seem to work it just locks up at that line. No exception just doesn't continue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, seems I'm on my own with this one. So far this is what I've found, for those who have a similar problem. Note that this varies by version, and I am running 2.3 Gingerbread.

I found 2 files in `/system/bin` - `screencap` and `screenshot`.

`screencap` returns a bitmap in a format I don't know how to decode, while `screenshot` makes a regular bmp file called tmpshot.bmp at the root of the sdcard (Neither accept any kind of command parameters. They don't seem to accept -h,-help, --help etc either).

tmpshot.bmp seems a viable solution for now but I was looking to avoid writing and reading from sdcard as this is quite the bottleneck. I will keep searching, but for those who need a solution now, here you are.

EDIT: Upon further trials I found the `screencap` binary from another rom (MIUI to be specific) actually offers a few more options, where (miui)`screencap -t png /sdcard/screen.png` yields a valid png screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);    
                    OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();
                    os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
                    os.flush();          
                    os.close();
                    sh.waitFor();
```

put it in a try catch block